# Pull 3 digits from middle of id and sort by even odd

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have file ids in my database that start with:

- a single character prefix
- a period
- a three digit client id
- a hyphen
- a three digit file number.

Example **F.129-123**

We have several ids for each client.
I need to be able to strip out the three digit file number and then pull them based on even or odd so that I can assign specific data to each result population.

One added issue. Some of the ids have characters added at the end. 
Example: `F.129-123A` or `F.129-123.NF`

So I need to be able to just use the three digit file number without any other characters, because the added characters create errors while conversion.

Comment: what have you tried so far, what DB are you using?

Comment: Use tags to specify the database engine and version? if you don't answer the comments, probably no one will pay attention to your question.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **`SQL SERVER`**,

you can use **[CHARINDEX()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql)** to find the index of `-` and then 
get 3 digits after `-` using **[SUBSTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql)**

```
SELECT substring('F.123-234',charindex('-','F.123-234')+1, 3)
```

If you are using **`MySQL`**,
you can use **[POSITION()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-position-function.php)** to find the index of `-` and then get 3 digits after `-` using **[SUBSTRING()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php)**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('F.123-234',POSITION( '-' IN 'F.123-234' )+1,3);
```

If you are using **`Oracle`**,

you can use **[INSTR()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm#OLADM564)** to find the index of `-` and then get 3 digits after `-` using **[SUBSTR()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm)**

**UPDATES:**

Based on the requirements in comments, you can use a query like below achieve what you need.

```
SELECT 
       SUBSTRING(MatterID,CHARINDEX('-',MatterID)+1, 3) as FileNo 
FROM 
       Matters 
WHERE 
       MatterID LIKE'f.129%' 
       AND MatterID NOT LIKE '%col%' 
       AND substring( MatterID, CHARINDEX('-',MatterID)+1, 3) % 2 = 0
```

Comment: The CHARINDEX works perfectly to reduce the IDs to just the 3 digits. I still need to find even and odd so that I can assign specific data to each subset. Here is what I tried and it does not work.

Comment: SELECT substring(MatterID,charindex('-',MatterID)+1, 3) as FileNo
from Matters
where MatterID like 'f.129%'
and MatterID not like '%col%'
and MatterID % 2 = 0

Comment: Matters is the table I am pulling from and MatterID is the column. I am using SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. Now all I need to do is create the Update statement to change the assigned professional to each. I'll let you know if I have any issues with that part. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @Fwiseguy You are welcome. Feel free to upvote and mark as correct if it helped :)

Comment: First time user, don't know how to up vote.  Any guidance?

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with Microsoft SQL Server, then you could use of `patindex()` function with `substring()` function to get the only 3 digits file number

```
select left(substring(string, PATINDEX('%[0-9][-]%', string)+2, LEN(string)), 3)
```

Note that if you have other `period (i.e. -, /)` then you will need to modify chars like `PATINDEX('%[0-9][/]%')`

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres you can use [`split_part()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) to get the part after the hyphen, then cast it to an integer:

```
select *
from the_table
order by split_part(file_id, '-', 2)::int;
```

This assumes that there is always exactly one `-` in the string. I understand your question that this is the case as the format is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful

```
    Create table #tmpFileNames(id int, FileName VARCHAR(50))

    insert into #tmpFileNames values(1,'F.129-123')
    insert into #tmpFileNames values(2,'F.129-125')
    insert into #tmpFileNames values(3,'F.129-124')
    insert into #tmpFileNames values(4,'F.129-123A')
    insert into #tmpFileNames values(5,'F.129-124B')
    insert into #tmpFileNames values(6,'F.129-125.PQ')
    insert into #tmpFileNames values(7,'F.129-123.NF')


    select SUBSTRING(STUFF(FileName, 1, CHARINDEX('-',FileName), ''),0,4), * from #tmpFileNames
    Order by SUBSTRING(STUFF(FileName, 1, CHARINDEX('-',FileName), ''),0,4),id


    Drop table #tmpFileNames
```